# I have the Kindle app on two of my Mac computers.

Tags: kindle, kindle-app

I have the Kindle app on two computers and both computers show the same purchased  books.  I want to delete the app and its content on my oldest computer. Will the books still appear on the new computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the books will still appear within the Kindle app on the new computer, provided that you are signed in to your account.

I believe you can be signed in to the kindle app on up to 6 devices, removing one device will not affect the books you have purchased (you may just need to re-download them on to the new device).